# How can I extract data from my SQL Server Dataset into a class that I can use?

Tags: c#, sql-server, datagrid, datagridview

I'm trying to make headway into a project that I started on a few days ago, I've spent all day reading up on ADO.net but I'm struggling to understand how I can extract my SQL server table data into a class that I can basically run a few calculations like "startTime - endTime = totalWorked" that will allow me to create a seperate form where I can Display my summaries.

I have the little code that i've done here, It connects to my database and creates a datagridview in the code. http://pastebin.com/VNRDqHjM

Can you give me some pointers on how to achieve want I want to do?

Thanks alot,
Ross

Answer (score 0):

One option is to put items into a DTO.  You can loop over an IDataReader (my preference) or a DataSet.

Imagine the IDataReader below is wired up to a "Select EmployeeKey, LastName, FirstName, HireDate from dbo.Employee;"

```
[Serializable]
public partial class Employee
{
    public int EmployeeKey { get; set; }                   
    public string LastName { get; set; }                   
    public string FirstName { get; set; }   
    public DateTime HireDate  { get; set; }  
}

[Serializable]
public class EmployeeCollection : List<Employee>
{
}   

internal static class EmployeeSearchResultsLayouts
{
    public static readonly int EMPLOYEE_KEY = 0;
    public static readonly int LAST_NAME = 1;
    public static readonly int FIRST_NAME = 2;
    public static readonly int HIRE_DATE = 3;
}


    public EmployeeCollection SerializeEmployeeSearchForCollection(IDataReader dataReader)
    {
        Employee item = new Employee();
        EmployeeCollection returnCollection = new EmployeeCollection();
        try
        {

            int fc = dataReader.FieldCount;//just an FYI value

            int counter = 0;//just an fyi of the number of rows

            while (dataReader.Read())
            {

                if (!(dataReader.IsDBNull(EmployeeSearchResultsLayouts.EMPLOYEE_KEY)))
                {
                    item = new Employee() { EmployeeKey = dataReader.GetInt32(EmployeeSearchResultsLayouts.EMPLOYEE_KEY) };

                    if (!(dataReader.IsDBNull(EmployeeSearchResultsLayouts.LAST_NAME)))
                    {
                        item.LastName = dataReader.GetString(EmployeeSearchResultsLayouts.LAST_NAME);
                    }

                    if (!(dataReader.IsDBNull(EmployeeSearchResultsLayouts.FIRST_NAME)))
                    {
                        item.FirstName = dataReader.GetString(EmployeeSearchResultsLayouts.FIRST_NAME);
                    }

                    if (!(dataReader.IsDBNull(EmployeeSearchResultsLayouts.HIRE_DATE)))
                    {
                        item.HireDate = dataReader.GetDateTime(EmployeeSearchResultsLayouts.HIRE_DATE);
                    }


                    returnCollection.Add(item);
                }

                counter++;
            }

            return returnCollection;

        }
        //no catch here... see  http://blogs.msdn.com/brada/archive/2004/12/03/274718.aspx
        finally
        {
            if (!((dataReader == null)))
            {
                try
                {
                    dataReader.Close();
                }
                catch
                {
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

After you values are in the DTO, you can add a read-only property like this:

```
public int DaysEmployed
{
    get
    {
        int returnValue = 0;
            returnValue = Convert.ToInt32 (DateTime.Now.Subtract(this.HireDate).TotalDays);
        return returnValue;
    }
}
```

Which will take advantage of your existing properties.

Keep in mind, you'll have to handle situations if you don't supply a HireDate to the object.
But you get the idea.

You ~can do this in a DataSet/DataTable with a computed column.  But that is "very 2004'ish" IMHO. 
DTO (or POCO's if you add some basic logic) are very time tested.

Answer (score 0):

I’d strongly suggest you check out some ORM software that does this automatically for you. Creating classes yourself and then filling them up with objects is time consuming and error prone. Nowadays there are tools that do all the work for you.

Check out the list of different options for .NET [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_object-relational_mapping_software#.NET).  I’d recommend those that are already built in into .NET framework but you can’t go wrong with any of these.