# Recommended database structure and retrieval using C#

Tags: c#, sql-server

I have a situation where I have a table of records that looks something like (detail removed for brevity):

```
CREATE TABLE Records (
    RecordsId int,
    Description varchar(255)
);
```

I want to add multiple comments for each record using another table such as:

```
CREATE TABLE Comments (
    CommentsId int,
    Comment varchar(255)
);
```

I am aware that I can link the tables using a join statement but how would I effectively retrieve the information if there was one Record with multiple comments attached to it, with no set number of comments?

Such as

```
RecordsId
Description
    - Comment 1
    - Comment 2
    - Comment 3
    - Comment .....
```

I am aware that I could run a query to get the value of the first table and then run a second query for the second table but this would be extremely slow when I  have large numbers of records. I am trying to popullate a C# object with the values.

Comment: This is a really broad question; first please pick a data access strategy/library/ORM and then we can offer more targeted advice. Your Comments table needs a RecordID column

Comment: If this were a greenfield site using C# what would you recommend?

Comment: If I were writing new code.I would use the Dapper ORM framework : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6317937/dapper-net-and-stored-proc-with-multiple-result-sets

Answer (score 1):

//add multiple comments for each record //

You need to add a FK from Comment back to Record.

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.Record (
    RecordKey int,
    Description varchar(255)
);

CREATE TABLE dbo.Comment (
    CommentsKey int,
    RecordKey int NOT NULL,
    Comment varchar(255)
);


ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Comment]
    ADD CONSTRAINT [FK_Comment_To_Record]
    FOREIGN KEY (RecordKey)
    REFERENCES [dbo].[Record] (RecordKey)
```

..

Other stuff:

Use a schema name to create tables/objects.  "dbo" is the built-in default.

I prefer singular noun for the tablename.  this is a holy-war.  I think the table should be the name of the ENTITY.  "Record" and "Comment" are the entitynames.  Again, this is a holy war.

I prefer MyObjectKey vs "Id".

Think about this.  What is an "EmployeeId"?  Is that a db-surrogate-key?  Or is that a value on a badge that an employee wears on their shirt?  "Id" is ambiguous.  "Key" is clearer IMHO.

......

As per your comment, "what would i use with new code?"

I would use Dapper ORM which is a micro orm, but performs really really well.

This article will get you there:

https://medium.com/dapper-net/handling-multiple-resultsets-4b108a8c5172

Pay attention to this comment:

> To avoid doing two roundtrips to the database to get customer and
>   orders data separately, the multiple resultset feature can be used:

Comment: Thank you but that will just prevent the links between the tables from being destoyed? How would I then retrieve a long list of the first table with a list for each row, created using the second table in a single query? On the subject of Key, yes that is an excellent point.

Comment: You need to learn how to serialize db-data into c# objects.  Thus the one comment form Caius about "what is your ORM?" . you can HAND-MAP using IDataREader.  see my answer this post : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16175972/how-can-i-extract-data-from-my-sql-server-dataset-into-a-class-that-i-can-use

Comment: Here is a another post about using IDataReader.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5758526/what-is-the-fastest-way-to-read-data-from-a-dbdatareader/5758573#5758573

Comment: FK is relatively optional, by the way.. The system would certainly work without an FK..